# How to close input stream of FTP inbound endpoint in Mule when streaming is used

Tags: java, file, file-io, mule

I have a very simple configuration which copies the file from FTP server to file outbound. I am using `streaming` for file transfer because of huge file sizes. This is my config:

```
 <ftp:connector name="ftpConnector" streaming="true" pollingFrequency="360000"/>

    <flow name="copyFTPtoFile">
        <ftp:inbound-endpoint name="FTP" connector-ref="ftpConnector" host="FTP" port="21" user="test" password="test" path="/Testenv" />
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="/vendor/in" />
    </flow>
```

I am not sure how to close the `input-stream` so that files are deleted from FTP server once they are copied.

Comment: Mule should take care of that automatically for you, isn't it the case?

Comment: not when I have `streaming=true` on ftp connector. _. If streaming is used on inbound endpoints it is the responsability of the user to close the input stream. If streaming is used on outbound endpoints Mule closes the stream automatically._ from this [link] http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/FTP+Transport+Reference

Comment: They probably mean if you receive the stream in a custom component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the payload is an `InputStream`, the following code of the [file outbound endpoint dispatcher](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/file/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageDispatcher.java#L83) will be executed:

```
InputStream is = event.transformMessage(DataTypeFactory.create(InputStream.class));
IOUtils.copyLarge(is, fos);
is.close();
```

So the stream should be automatically closed for you.

Comment: but flies are not deleted from FTP server if I have `streaming=true`. If I remove `streaming=true` on FTP connector, then files get automatically deleted

Comment: That sounds like another question to me.

Comment: You're right. Though I intend to ask how to delete files but had this notion that if input stream is closed, files will be deleted automatically

Comment: Not with FTP, deletion happens in a post-processing step of the inbound message dispatch and only if there is no pending FTP command.

Comment: I opened another question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366159/why-does-mule-ftp-connector-doesnt-delete-file-when-streaming-is-enabled. Can you please throw some light